# Passing data to a component I guess

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I'm trying to Get this Part to my View at the bottom of the code...

the data comes in the console but i need it to display and be able to be manipulated into Miles

I've been trying different things and cant get it to work..

Im new to this stuff..

```js
//JavaScript here
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
HTML HERE
```

```
    console.log(`Distance: ${result.distance} km`);
       
    console.log(`Duration: ${result.duration} min.`)
```

```
    
      return (
        <View>
          <MapView
            style={{height: '70%', width: '100%'}}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 39.12690965849537,
              longitude: -77.548617094021614,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}>
            <MapViewDirections
              origin={originLoc}
              destination={destinationLoc}
              apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
              strokeWidth={5}
              strokeColor="orange"
              onReady={result => {
                //MapData.distance = result.distance;
                //MapData.duration = result.duration;
                console.log(`Distance: ${result.distance} km`);
                console.log(`Duration: ${result.duration} min.`);
              }}
            />
    
            <Marker coordinate={originLoc} title={'Origin'} />
            <Marker
              coordinate={destinationLoc}
              title={'Destination'}
              pinColor={'orange'}
            />
          </MapView>
    
          <View>
            <Text>I am Iron Man!!!</Text>
            <Text>
              distance : {MapData.distance} km.time : {MapData.duration} min
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Comment: Please make a working example of whatever it is you are attempting and isolate to the one issue you are experiencing (I suggest a snippet of your code - use the button to create/edit one)

Comment: I added an empty snippet for you to work from

Comment: Is this react Native.

Comment: Im trying to get this data here

  console.log(`Distance: ${result.distance} km`);
   console.log(`Duration: ${result.duration} min.`);

Into the 

 <View>
            <Text>I am Iron Man!!!</Text>
            <Text>
              distance : {MapData.distance} km.time : {MapData.duration} min
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

Comment: Anyone?? Can help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using UseState hook.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
 const [distance, setdistance] = useState(0);   
 const [duration, setduration] = useState(0);

 return (
    <View>
      <MapView
        style={{height: '70%', width: '100%'}}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 39.12690965849537,
          longitude: -77.548617094021614,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}>
        <MapViewDirections
          origin={originLoc}
          destination={destinationLoc}
          apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
          strokeWidth={5}
          strokeColor="orange"
          onReady={result => {
            setdistance(`${result.distance}`);
            setduration(`${result.duration}`);
            console.log(`Distance: ${result.distance} km`);
            console.log(`Duration: ${result.duration} min.`);
          }}
        />
    <Marker coordinate={originLoc} title={'Origin'} />
        <Marker
          coordinate={destinationLoc}
          title={'Destination'}
          pinColor={'orange'}
        />
      </MapView>

      <View>
        <Text>I am Iron Man!!!</Text>
        <Text>
           { distance }
           {' '}
           KM.time 
           :
           { Math.trunc(duration) || '0'}
           {' '}
           Min
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```